# whirlpool tub faucet mixer **spraying** in the ceiling of first floor

Tags: leak, faucet, bathtub, jetted

I have a Kohler whirlpool tub on second floor, not used for months, and when I switch on either the hot or cold faucet, it leaks all over in the ceiling of first floor room, but no water comes in the tub
It appears to me that the mixer valve is leaking as it leaks when either the hot or cold water is turned on

Which tiles (numbered) to break to best access it (picture attached). The access panel is pretty far I think..Would be much obliged for your advise!!  Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Why not start with the access panel and then see where the pipes run? A whirlpool tub will have a pump which may well be directly behind the access panel.

Comment: I agree with Graham, open it up and see it you can see the actual place it is leaking/spraying.

Comment: Thanks guys. it appears the tile, the contractor put in the access panel is kinda jammed in-- lets hope he didn't stick it in. will report back. if it doesn't show me the leak which numbered tiled would be best going after next? many thanks!!

Comment: Ok guys. Found the problem after breaking through the access panel. there is a pipe where the welding has come off (picture attached)-- will have to access it from top. My question is what suggestions would you have for making an access panel door in a way that can be accessed and if I want to stick a tile so it looks homogenous-- any ideas? I had seen some magnetic kinda doors